# How can I prevent OS X to switch the keyboard layout at startup and on admin password request?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I switched my keyboard layout on my new Macbook Pro 13" retina from German to UK. This works fine most of the time, but when I boot my system I have to insert my password with the German layout.

The same happens when my Mac requires the admin password. When I install a new app I have to insert my admin password and the dialog switches always to German layout.

Is there a way to switch the "global" keyboard layout, not just the layout of my account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Two ways, in fact.

The wrong way: reinstall osx and select the keyboard you want.

The right way: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4099

That links says that you should:

1. go to system prefs,
2. Go to 'users and groups'
3. Select 'login options'. Authenticate (if needed)
4. Select 'Show input menu in login window'
5. Log out
6. Select the new keyboard
7. Log in
8. Enjoy

I actually never had a problem with the admin prompt being in another keyboard. Maybe this will fix it.