# alternate osx default keyboard after reboot?

Tags: macos, keyboard, default-settings, dotfiles, colemak

Is there a way to set Colemak as my default keyboard on startup?  Can this be done in shell using "defaults write"?  I'd like to include it in my setup script.

I did enable "Show input menu in login window" but I still have to manually switch it from qwerty to colemak after rebooting.
[superuser osx keyboard switch](https://superuser.com/questions/545570/how-can-i-prevent-os-x-to-switch-the-keyboard-layout-at-startup-and-on-admin-pas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist /Library/Preferences
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solution worked.  I can not upvote yet.